# Flexible/responsive boxes weird browser behavior in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design, fluid-layout

Safari: Works

Firefox: Weird floating issue on initial page load, works after browser resize

Chrome: End boxes jump around quickly when making window smaller
(have not tested other browsers)

Video displaying browser issues: http://tinypic.com/r/2gxo8w3/6

Full script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<style>
.box {
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #999;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
#boxes {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
.end-box {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.top-box {
    margin-top: 0;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id='boxes'>
    <div class='box'>1</div>
    <div class='box'>2</div>
    <div class='box'>3</div>
    <div class='box'>4</div>
    <div class='box'>5</div>
    <div class='box'>6</div>
    <div class='box'>7</div>
    <div class='box'>8</div>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
columns = Math.floor($('#boxes').width()/225); //min box/column size (before spacing)
var spacing = ((columns - 1) * 10/$('#boxes').width())*100; //10px spacing between boxes
$('.box').width(100/columns-spacing/columns+'%');
$('.box:nth-child('+columns+'n+0)').addClass('end-box');//removes margins
$('.box:nth-child(-n'+columns+')').addClass('top-box');

$(window).resize(function() {
    columnsCheck = Math.floor($('#boxes').width()/225);
    if(columns != columnsCheck) {
        $('.end-box').removeClass('end-box');
        $('.top-box').removeClass('top-box');
        $('.box:nth-child('+columnsCheck+'n+0)').addClass('end-box');
    }
    columns = columnsCheck;
    var spacing = ((columns - 1) * 10/$('#boxes').width())*100;
    $('.box').width(100/columns-spacing/columns+'%');
    $('.box:nth-child('+columns+'n+0)').addClass('end-box');
    $('.box:nth-child(-n'+columns+')').addClass('top-box');
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I solve this issue (while maintaining 10px margins). I am also open to alternative methods of creating this effects via JavaScript/jQuery (trying to avoid pure CSS3).

Comment: why are you using javascript for this? It should be done with CSS and Media Queries....

Comment: Cross-browser support is why, this is meant to be used as a polyfill.

Comment: All the browsers you're testing in support media queries.

Comment: I'm well aware of this, but many browsers do not support calc() or flex boxes, particularly mobile browsers. I am developing the solution using the browsers I have installed first. When I have a working solution I will test it in older browsers, until then I just want to get it working.

Comment: Also I think it's worth noting that the size is based on the parent element, irrelevant to screen/device size, which is how I want it. So media queries actually wouldn't even work on this.

Comment: Media queries *would* work on this. If your box widths are percentage based, it is based off the parent, not the window.